# Bash mysql error handling locked tables

Tags: mysql, linux, database, bash, shell

i have a shell script that is called with a few parameters very frequently. it is supposed to build a query and execute the statement. in case an error occures, it should write the arguments seperated into a file so the error-handling can take place by calling that script again.

everything works but

the problem is, i catch connection refused error etc but if the statement cannot be executed because the table is locked and i do not want to wait for the timeout.

my code:

```
...
mysql -u ${username} -p${password} -h ${database} -P ${port} --connect-timeout=1 --skip-reconnect -e "$NQUERY"
    mysqlstatus=$?
    if [ $mysqlstatus -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "[ERROR:QUERY COULD NOT BE EXECUTED:$mysqlstatus: QUERY WRITTEN TO LOG]" >> ${GENLOG} 
        #echo ${NQUERY} >> ${FQUER} 
        for i in "$@"; do
            ARGS="$ARGS $i|"
        done
        echo "${ARGS}" >> ${ARGLOG}
    else
        echo "[OK] $NQUERY" >> ${GENLOG}
    fi
...
```

but when a table is locked, the executing is not canceled and it runs like forever..

its not a solution for me to set the Max_statement_time_set or anything on the mysql server, since im not the only one using the db

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timeout command along with mysql

```
timeout 3 mysql -u ...
```

This will wait 3 seconds for the mysql command to return, if the command runs longer then 3 seconds timeout will return exit status 124 to the shell. If you don't have timeout you can use job control with something like this.

```
#background the process
mysql -u ... &

#get pid of background process
bg_pid=$!

sleep 3

#check if your pid is still running
#using string matching incase pid was re assigned
if [[ $(ps -p $bg_pid -o args --no-headers) =~ "mysql" ]]
then
    echo "running to long"
else
    echo "OK"
fi
```